# current_timestamp doesn't exist in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database that is about Heroku. A field is automatically filled with the date. I try to use `current_timestamp`, but it does not seem to work.

Here is the schema of the database.

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users (
  id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar,
  email varchar,
  username varchar,
  password varchar,
  register_date CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() not null
);
```

Here is the query:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, username, password) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, email, username, password))
```

And here is the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
LINE 7:   register_date CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() not null
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) doesn't recognize `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` that's why you have to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (without parentheses). Next create table query must work for you:

```
create table users (
  id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar,
  email varchar,
  username varchar,
  password varchar,
  register_date timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null
);
```

To check that it works just run next query from postgres REPL:

```
insert into users(name, email, username, password)
values('n', 'e@e.com', 'un', 'pwd');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
However I then get `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "not"`

Comment: Yes, I think that this answer should have some more code and explanation so that it does not confuse.

Comment: @AliceAntoine Updated my answer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Done!)

Comment: Great. One nit: `current_timestamp` *is* a function, just one without parentheses as decreed by the SQL standard.

Answer (score 1):

To add a column with default current timestamp you could use [TIMESTAMP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-datetime.html) type with default value as [`NOW()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

```
create table users (
  id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar,
  email varchar,
  username varchar,
  password varchar,
  register_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

Sample data

```
INSERT INTO users(name, email, username, password)
VALUES('Foo', 'foo@bar.com', 'bar', 'foobar')
```

[Demo with 9.6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f6720/1)

[Demo with 10](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kvLQd5wwmF55jFMooZN6pR/0)